# Any way to get strongest edge local to a contour line using cv2 or scikit-image?

Tags: image-processing, scikit-image, opencv, python

I am working on accurately segmenting objects from an image.

I have found contour lines by using a simple rectangular prism in HSV space as a color filter (followed by some morphological operations on the resulting mask to clear up noise). I found this approach to be better than applying canny edge detection to the whole image as that just picked up a lot of other edges I don't care about.
Is there a way to go about refining the contour line I have extracted such that it clips to the strongest local edge kind of like Adobe Photoshop's smart cropping utility?
Here's an image of what I mean

[image]

You can see a boundary between the sky blue and the gray. The dark blue is a drawn on contour. I'd like to somehow clip this to the nearby edge. It also looks like there are other lines in the grey region, so I think the algorithm should do some sort of more globalish optimisation to ensure that the "clipping" action doesn't jump randomly between my boundary of interest and the nearby lines.

Comment: can you please post the original image, your code, and the desired output? [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @Bilal I can't post the original image as its under NDA. The code might not be relevant as I'm asking for existence of a functionality. If snapping lines to nearest strong edges is a thing, then a link will suffice.

Comment: https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/auto_examples/segmentation/plot_morphsnakes.html or https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/auto_examples/edges/plot_active_contours.html . The source code for this repo also probably has what you need: https://github.com/PyIFT/livewire-gui

Comment: @Juan I tried all 3 of these. LiveWire was great. The second link was somewhat suitable but failed because my object has square corners and the smoothness parameter does not dynamically adapt. The first link was generally good but didn't allow for finer targetting. Feel free to drop a proper response and I can mark as solved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some ideas to try:

- Morphological snakes: https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/auto_examples/segmentation/plot_morphsnakes.html
- Active contours: https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/auto_examples/edges/plot_active_contours.html
- Whatever livewire is doing under the hood: https://github.com/PyIFT/livewire-gui

Based on [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65643004/any-way-to-get-strongest-edge-local-to-a-contour-line-using-cv2-or-scikit-image?noredirect=1#comment116130316_65643004), the last one is the most useful.